# Why does this 1-dimensional Perlin Noise Generator Return Values > 1?

Tags: kotlin, noise, perlin-noise

For educational purposes I want to implement the 1-dimensional `Perlin Noise` algorithm in Kotlin. I familiarized myself with the algorithm [here](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2018/cmsc425/Lects/lect14-perlin.pdf) and [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20160530124230/http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm).

I think I understood the basic concept, however **my implementation can return values greater than 1**. I expect the result of the call `perlin(x)` to be in the range 0 to 1. I can't figure out where I'm mistaken, so maybe someone can point me in the right direction. For simplicity I use simple linear interpolation instead of *smoothstep* or other advanced techniques for now.

```kotlin
class PerlinNoiseGenerator(seed: Int, private val boundary: Int = 10) {
    private var random = Random(seed)
    private val noise = DoubleArray(boundary) {
        random.nextDouble()
    }

    fun perlin(x: Double, persistence: Double = 0.5, numberOfOctaves: Int = 8): Double {
        var total = 0.0
        for (i in 0 until numberOfOctaves) {
            val amplitude = persistence.pow(i) // height of the crests
            val frequency = 2.0.pow(i) // number of crests per unit distance
            val octave = amplitude * noise(x * frequency)
            total += octave
        }
        return total
    }

    private fun noise(t: Double): Double {
        val x = t.toInt()
        val x0 = x % boundary
        val x1 = if (x0 == boundary - 1) 0 else x0 + 1
        val between = t - x
        
        val y0 = noise[x0]
        val y1 = noise[x1]
        return lerp(y0, y1, between)
    }

    private fun lerp(a: Double, b: Double, alpha: Double): Double {
        return a + alpha * (b - a)
    }
}
```

For example if you would use these random generated noises

```kotlin
private val noise = doubleArrayOf(0.77, 0.02, 0.63, 0.74, 0.49, 0.22, 0.19, 0.76, 0.16, 0.08)
```

You would end up with an image like this:

[image: Generated 1D Perlin Noise]

where the green line is the calculated `Perlin Noise` of `8` octaves with a persistence of `0.5`. As you can see the sum of all octaves at x=0 for example is greater than 1. (The blue line being the first octave `noise(x)` and the orange one being the second octave `0.5 * noise(2x)`).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

**Note**: I'm aware that the `Simplex Noise` algorithm is the successor of `Perlin Noise`, however for educational purposes I want to implement `Perlin Noise` first. I'm also aware that my boundary should be set to something in the magnitude of 256 but for simplicity I just used 10 for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been digging around and found [this article](http://adrianb.io/2014/08/09/perlinnoise.html) which introduces a value to normalize the results returned by `Perlin(x)`. Essentially the amplitudes are summed up and the total is divided by this value. This seems to make sense since we could have "bad luck" and have a y-value of 1.0 in the first octave, followed by a 0.5 in the next, etc. So dividing by the sum of the amplitudes (1.5 in this case with 2 octaves) seems reasonable to keep the values in the range 0 - 1.

However, I'm unsure if this is the preferred way since none of the other resource uses this technique.

The modified code would look like this:

```kotlin
    fun perlin(x: Double, persistence: Double = 0.5, numberOfOctaves: Int = 8): Double {
        var total = 0.0
        var amplitudeSum = 0.0 //used for normalizing results to 0.0 - 1.0
        for (i in 0 until numberOfOctaves) {
            val amplitude = persistence.pow(i) // height of the crests
            val frequency = 2.0.pow(i) // frequency (number of crests per unit distance) doubles per octave
            val octave = amplitude * noise(x * frequency)
            total += octave
            amplitudeSum += amplitude
        }
        return total / amplitudeSum
    }
```